# How to find in runtime access/error log LogFormat in Apache?

Tags: apache-2.2, apache-1.3

I want to parse access_log and error_log of multiple apache server. But I don't know the LogFormat while parsing the logs. So before that I want to know the LogFormat which has been configured in each Apache.

- One way is I can parse first httpd.conf and Find LogFormat and CustomeLog" string and get the log format. Is there any other way to check in runtime logformat by any command or apache utility ?
- Is LogFormat "common, combined etc" has been fix things ? If yes that Can I build different regEx for each type ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using debian/ubuntu, LogFormat is defined in /etc/apache2/apache2.conf.

An easier way to do it is use logwatch, which by default come with apache log scanning. It can even email the report.

Post comment or update your question if you need more instruction.